# How to find sets of <li> and wrap with <ul> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on an internal application for generating markup from pasted email content, and as I'm only a designer, I'm using the only thing I kind of know: jQuery. I've managed to piece together enough so that I'm getting this:

```
<p>Some paragraph content is here.</p>

<li>list item 1a
<li>list item 1b
<li>list item 1c

<p>More paragraph content is here.</p>

<li>list item 2a
<li>list item 2b
<li>list item 2c
```

So I'm getting list items without an unordered list element. There may be multiple lists, as in the above example. How can I add the ul's so that they wrap correctly around the list items?

Comment: Is that the content of a TEXTAREA element or is it in the DOM?

Comment: In the DOM - it's coming from a textarea and being output into a div.

Comment: Do not do that. Since that HTML source code is invalid (LI elements must be children of an UL or OL element), the browser will **interpret that HTML code incorrectly** - in this particular case, the second P element will be placed **inside** the preceding LI element. Never insert invalid HTML code into the DOM!

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to rethink my strategy on this. I can't seem to get this working by outputting the content into a textarea. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could help you?

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: +1: I would include an example. Just paste some of the relevant code from the link.